# Linq to Sql - all nullable datatype

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

Whenever I am drag & drop any procedure on the surface of linq to sql file, and when I am looking in designer.cs file, all data types are nullable (whether they are in db or not).

I can manually make change in designer.cs file from  nullable to not null

but any other solution is there for this problem?

Comment: data types that you get from procedure or that you pass to it?

Comment: @teovankot data types which I am getting from procedure. all these types are nullable by default whether they are nullable or not in database.

Comment: That's really good question. I believe the only solution that might work is to create temp table, fill it in procedure and return. How to do it you can find in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443663/how-to-return-temporary-table-from-stored-procedure). Let me know if it works plz.

Comment: @teovankot hi thanks for solution but I have more than 100 tables in db so to create temp table for each of this table, its create one more overhead.

Comment: I guess, there is no other solutions for your problem =(